# why spark files not included in publishe folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publishing, spark-view-engine

I tried file system publish and ftp
I'm using VS2010 and .net 4.0

should i somehow include *.spark ext files to the MSBuild?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this](http://groups.google.com/group/spark-dev/browse_thread/thread/426c203e82de0b3b). You basically have to set `.spark` files' *Build Action* to *Content*.

Here's a macro to do so:

```
Sub SetSparkBuildAction(ByVal scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, ByVal action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildBegin 
    For Each proj As Project In DTE.Solution.Projects 
        RecurseSetSparkBuildAction(proj) 
    Next 
End Sub 
Sub RecurseSetSparkBuildAction(ByVal item As Object) 
    If (item.Name.EndsWith(".spark", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) Then 
        item.Properties.Item("BuildAction").Value = 2 
    End If 
    For Each childItem As ProjectItem In item.ProjectItems 
        RecurseSetSparkBuildAction(childItem) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

To use this macro, open up *Macros IDE* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), locate *EnvironmentEvents* in a leftmost treeview and paste this code *outside* of the *"Automatically generated code, do not modify"* region.

Comment: thanks, could u tell me please, where should i put this macro? it looks like VB code :)

Comment: @msony: Clarified a bit. See if that helps.

Comment: it tried it, but can see that buildAction fired when i press on publish btn, should i do something else?